# Vendor recipe for a rare item

Tags: path-of-exile

For one of the Perandus League challanges I need to do some vendor crafting. However I can't find the recipe to get a rare item by selling certain items to the vendor.

Can someone give me the recipe/an example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few recipes [in the Wiki](http://pathofexile.gamepedia.com/Vendor_recipe_system#Equipment).

Substituting magic items for rares will complete the magic item crafting part of the challenge as well.

Examples:

- x5 rares items of the same base type = rare of the same base type
- 1 rare of each two-stone ring = rare prismatic ring
- 2 different rare amber/lapis/jade amulets = rare agate/turquoise/citrine amulets depending on combination given

Side note: Another challenge requires creating a prismatic ring so I would recommend finding the 3 rare two-stone rings to make a prismatic and completing both challenges at the same time.

Comment: > finding the 3 rare two-stone rings -- or you may craft them from any two-stone rings you happen to have.

Comment: `3 rare two-stone rings to make a prismatic and completing both challenges at the same time.` Good idea, I will do that. I already had a magic item crafted, but thanks. I wonder how I'll ever get the orb of chance though :/

Comment: @BadAtPHP The orb of chance recipe is similar to the chaos orb recipe. You need a full set of rare gear, or a slightly more difficult one is the 2 rares with the same name.

Answer (score 3):

7 x Iron Rings and 1 x Rare (Paua/Coral) Ring will give you 1 x Rare (Paua/Coral) Amulet.

More generally, 5 x Rare items of the same base type (e.g. 5 x rare Goat Horns) will return one new rare item of the same type.